# Why was my bounty removed?

Tags: discussion, moderation, bounty

I started a bounty to bring attention to my question [Why did Romero cast a Black actor as the lead?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/76391/23541)

The bounty mechanism allows for bringing attention to a question specifically.

Now am am being accused of "ulterior motives".

Please explain.

Comment: When did **A bounty to draw attention to the need for this question to be closed and deleted. It's obviously bad due to the downvotes received.** become a valid reason to place a bounty?

Comment: Maybe you should learn the definition of ulterior motive and the be nice policy first before asking questions like that.

Comment: If you think your close vote has not drawn enough attention, you can always come by chat and post your question there. Placing a bounty on it sounds like an overshot.

Comment: @cde "ulterior motive: An alternative or extrinsic reason for doing something". Reason for leaving a bounty: to reward a particularly good question. _Ulterior Motive_: to attract attention to a bad question.

Comment: I don't understand this. If you regret asking the question, you could flag a moderator and ask for it to be dissociated from your account (I don't see why though, the question seems fine to me: as I understand it that film's casting *was* considered historically unusual in the context of segregation-era USA). If you're trying to make a statement... erm, whatever it is, it isn't really coming across. Maybe a blog or chat would be better?

Comment: @user you can't flag for that, it will be denied.

Comment: @ku "draw More attention to a question" is a bounty reason.

Comment: @cde not necessarily, I've had a question dissociated from my account by a moderator before now. If you think the mod is denying it for a spurious reason you can ask SE staff to do it too, there's an email address somewhere in the help pages

Comment: @user I've had those flags straight out refused.

Comment: You've had posts disassociated from your account before, by your request, as recently as June 9.  Why are you saying it will be denied?

Comment: @cde draw attention to a question _to get better answers_ is a bounty reason. Indeed, _all_ bounty reasons are implicitly about getting better answers and/or rewarding existing ones. None of them have anything to do with trying to bypass the SE deletion rules.

Comment: @Ian thank you for officially stating the last date. That's great evidence. It also ignored the flags denied for asking about this, and the denied flags saying to use the contact us link.

Comment: Great evidence of what exactly?  I never claimed that I could tell when you've been denied this - but you are implying that you cannot flag for this because it '*will* be denied'

Comment: @iandotkelly don't worry, it will be evident enough soon.

Comment: Just for the record: You were never denied *disassociation* at all (though, you might have been delegated to the SE CMs, since normal moderators can't actually do that, but you were never denied it, as ian pointed out). What you *have* been denied is *deleting* valuable content as well as flags asking for that. This is also why we know that you are generally well aware of the distinction between deletion and disassociation, despite what your confusion here might suggest.

Answer (score 8):

Let me explain first the motive of bounty.

From [Help Center page for bounty](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/bounty)(emphasis mine),

> If you’ve asked a good question, edited it with status and progress updates, and still are not receiving answers, you can draw attention to your question by placing a bounty on it.
>
> You can also choose from a list of bounty reasons to help other users understand why you’re dissatisfied with any current answers to the question. **If you need to describe something in more detail, there’s also optional, additional custom text that will be displayed with the bounty reason.**

Here is the list of bounty reasons from the [blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/09/23/bounty-reasons-and-post-notices/).

> Authoritative reference needed
>
> > Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources.
>
> Canonical answer required
>
> > The question is widely applicable to a large audience. A detailed canonical answer is required to address all the concerns.
>
> Current answers are outdated
>
> > The current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision given recent changes.
>
> Draw attention
>
> > This question has not received enough attention.
>
> Improve details
>
> > The current answers do not contain enough detail.
>
> Reward existing answer
>
> > One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty.

It's clear that you can start a bounty to get or award good answers.

The reason you have put for the bounty was

> **A bounty to draw attention to the need for this question to be closed and deleted. It's obviously bad due to the downvotes received.**

This is not the valid reason. You can't start a bounty to get your question closed and deleted even when it has a good answer.

Comment: Ignoring the "draw attention to the question" option.

Comment: For that purpose there is flags and even question with positive scores are not expected to be deleted on OP's request. Ask responsibly and respect your choice after that.

Comment: @cde ignoring the bouty are not flags

Comment: There is nothing that says a bounty can't be used to draw community attention to close vote issues.

Comment: @cde To get close votes, you can simply cast a close vote on your question. You're always allowed to do that even when you don't have Close Votes privileges. Once you have VTCed your question, it will get in CV queue where community will decide its fate.

Comment: And when that doesn't get enough attention, a bounty of draw attention Is used.

Comment: @cde It just needs attention of 5 users, at least. And your question has now +ve score. But still, it's not a good cause to start a bounty.

Comment: So your saying that it needs more attention from users. I wonder what mechanism exists for that. Oh wait...

Comment: @cde You can also flag it for moderator attention, which is the ultimate attention. ;-)

Comment: Are you suggesting to abuse the flag system with something that is explicitly stated it's not used for?

Comment: so abusing bounty is fine?

Comment: @cde flagging a question because you don't have permissions to do what you want is  _exactly what moderator flags are for_. The reality is, you know you're asking for something you shouldn't be so you know the moderators won't do it. You could try asking them to anonymize the question instead.